# Como puedo recibir eventos por teclado usando ESC del boton de escape o el boton de flecha abajo en Dart Puro, estoy haciendo un TETRIS

Tags: dart, entrada, teclado

Este es mi codigo (No se si esta bien del todo, soy principiante, pero por ahora quiero
resolver la entrada por teclado por los botones de las flechas de abajo y a los lados).
En la funcion de tetris() esta un bucle while, fue una solucion que me dio ChatGPT pero
no funciono, al correr el programa si me da la opcion de ingresar por consola pero al
pulsar el boton esc o la flecha abajo no sucede nada. Lo que deseo es pulsar la flecha
abajo y que la pieza de tetris baje, igualmente con los lados, pero quisiera me ayudaran
con la sintaxis correcta para poder recibir estos botones por entrada de consola. Espero
se haya entendido un poco mi requerimiento y disculpen si no se entiende muy bien, estoy
un poco abrumada :D

```
enum Movement {
  down,
  left,
  right,
}

void tetris() {
  var screen = [
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];

  printScreen(screen);

  while (true) {
    final event = stdin.readLineSync();

    if (event == "esc") {
      break;
    } else if (event == "down") {
      movePiece(screen, Movement.down);
    }
  }
}

void printScreen(var screen) {

  print("\nPantalla Tetris:\n");

  for (var row in screen) {

    print(row);
  }
}

void movePiece(
  List screen,
  Movement move,
) {

  var newScreen = [
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];

  for (var row in screen) {
    for (var item in row) {
      if (item == "") {
        var new_row_index = 0;
        var new_column_index = 0;

        switch (move) {
          case Movement.down:
            new_row_index = row + 1;
            new_column_index = item;
          case Movement.left:
          case Movement.right:
        }

        newScreen[new_row_index][new_column_index] = "";
        printScreen(newScreen);
      }
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  tetris();
}


No me funciono el bucle While que me dio CHATGPT, no sucede nada al presional esc o la flecha habia abajo
```